# how to set session in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a website in Joomla which contain course fields.

Each course field has different url.I have to check that if user is logged in then it will

redirect to that course.If user is not logged in then it will redirect to login page.how do i

check using session.

Please help me sought it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add [JFactory/getUser](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser) function to check if user is loged in and if not to use [JApplication::redirect](http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JApplication::redirect) to redirect him to desired url.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

if (!$user->guest) {
  echo "You are logged in";
} else {
  $login_url = "index.php?option=com_users&view=login";
  $app->redirect($login_url,'message to display','message');
}
```

**EDIT:**

There are built in methods in joomla to display content only to registered users without any coding.

For articles:

```
Content -> Article Manager -> *Article_name -> Access: Registered
```

For Menu Items:

```
Menus -> *Menu_name -> *Menu_item_title -> Access: Registered
```

There is also an option to set redirect link after login.

For Menu item login page:

```
Menus -> *Menu_Name -> New -> Menu Item Type: (Users Manager -> Login Form) -> Options -> Login Redirect
```

For Login Module:

```
Extensions -> Module Manager -> New -> Login -> Login Redirection Page
```

*A quick tip if you haven't login button in your menu is to create a new 'hidden' menu (that won't exist in any frontend position) and place the 'login redirection url' there.

Good Luck!